# Struts 1 MessageRessources - argument

Tags: java, struts

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<bean:message bundle="MyBundle" key="mytext.text" 
    arg0='<input  type="text"  name="text"  value="<%=num %>"'/>
```

I know that it is possible to pass an HTML element, but I will end up with an input box with the value "`<%=num%>`" instead the actual value of that variable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot combine scriptlet with a string for a tag argument, like you see the scriptlet is not evaluated so try that:

```
<% String s = "<input  type=\"text\"  name=\"text\"  value=\""+ num +"\""  %> 
<bean:message bundle="MyBundle" key="mytext.text" arg0="<%= s %>"/>
```

Take note that the input tag is not closed as in the example you provided.